# KDB to JKS keystore conversion

Tags: java, ibm-mq, tls1.2

I am new to TLS in java. I have files with KDB, RDB, and STN extensions.
How can I setup a JKS keystore and use that in a java application to implement TLS, which uses IBM WebSphere MQ client?

My doubts are:

1. Can I use ikeyman for the conversion?
2. Can I convert the KDB files directly to JKS keystore?
3. Do I need any other certificates to imlpement TLS in the IBM native MQ test application?
4. How can I add the TLS parameters to IBM Native MQ API?

I have tried to launch ikeyman. But I can't.

Comment: Did one id the answers help you solve your problem?   If it did please accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You do not mention which version of the MQ client you are using, for the purpose of this answer I will assume you are using a MQ client 7.1 or later.

---

You can build a Java Key Store (jks) from a source kdb file.

This will take two steps to complete:

1. Create an empty Java Key Store (jks):

   `runmqckm -keydb -create -db target.jks -type jks`
   This will prompt for a password that will be used to protect the jks file.
2. Import all certs from the source kdb file to the target jks file created above:

   `runmqckm -cert -import -db source.kdb -type cms -target target.jks -target_type jks`
   This will prompt for two passwords, the first is the password of the kdb file, the second is the password of the jks file.  If you add the flag '-stashed' it will eliminate the first password prompt.
3. You can then list the certs contained in both the kdb and the jks to compare and validate that all certs were copied over:

   `runmqckm -cert -list -db source.kdb -type cms -stashed`
   The command above will NOT prompt for a password because of the `-stashed` flag.

   `runmqckm -cert -list -db target.jks -type jks`
   The command above WILL prompt for the jks password.

---

### Notes

1. The kdb/rdb/sth files together represent an IBM Certificate Management Services (CMS) keystore.
2. There is a `-keydb -convert` option that indicates it should have the same outcome as the two steps I provided above, however I have noted that it does not always copy all of the certs.

Comment: Thank you, this is an extremely helpful and detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, but you can use `key tool` to create a `.jks` keystone and import the server certificate or truststore certificate.

```
keytool -keystore clientkey.jks -storetype jks -importcert -file servercert.pem -alias server-cert
```

Look in the TLS section in https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-patterns

Answer (score 0):

Java supports JKS and PKCS12 key store types. It also distinguishes between keyStore (which contains client certificates) and trustStore (which contains trusted certificates). Both keyStore and trustStore are needed.

Client certificates (keyStore) can be exported from .kdb directly by gsk8capicmd_64 command:

```
gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -export -db file.kdb -pw your_password -target file.p12 -target_pw your_password
```

TrustStore .jks can be created by exporting trusted certificates from .kdb and inserting them to new .jks:

```
for CERT_LABEL in $(gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -list -db file.kdb -pw your_password | grep ^! | cut -f2);
do
    gsk8capicmd_64 -cert -extract -db file.kdb -pw your_password -label ${CERT_LABEL} -target temp.cert;
    yes | keytool -importcert -alias ${CERT_LABEL} -file temp.cert -keystore file.jks -storepass your_password;
done;
```

KeyStore and trustStore can be then configured on command line or directly in the code this way:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "file.p12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "your_password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "pkcs12");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "file.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "your_password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType", "jks");
```

Comment: See my answer, you can do the same direct to a jks with two commands, no loop required, using the runmqckm command that is supplied with IBM MQ.