# how to connect to queue manager with TLS enabled in ibm-mq

Tags: java, ssl, ibm-mq

I am writing one java client application to connect to IBM-MQ queue manager configured in TLS.
Below is java code:

```
import com.ibm.mq.MQC;
import com.ibm.mq.MQEnvironment;
import com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager;
//import com.ibm.mq.constants.CMQC;

public class IBMMQClient {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\ibm_mq\\temp\\genkey.kdb");

        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "gen@123");

        MQEnvironment.hostname = "*************";//removed hostname for privacy
        MQEnvironment.port = 1419; // set the port number of the queue manager

        MQEnvironment.channel = "MYSSL.SVRCONN"; // set the channel name

        MQEnvironment.userID = "myuser";
        MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"; // set the cipher suite to use for SSL/TLS


        MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY,MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);


        MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("MYSSL");
        System.out.println("Connected to " + qMgr.getName());
        qMgr.disconnect();
   }
}
```

But I am getting error as:
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2393'.

Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

```
bash-4.2$ mqrc 2393

      2393  0x00000959  MQRC_SSL_INITIALIZATION_ERROR
```

So wanted to know what should be proper way to connect to it.
As .kdb file it is treating as invalid keystore format.

Below are the commands which I used to create keystore .kdb at queue manager side and java client application side:

queue manager MYSSL settings: -

```
cd /var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl

Creating key store:
---------------------------
runmqakm -keydb -create -db mysslkey.kdb -pw myssl@123 -type cms -stash

Creating self signed certficate
------------------------------
runmqakm -cert -create -label ibmwebspheremqmyssl -db mysslkey.kdb -dn "CN=myssl,OU=IBM" -expire 365 -size 1024 -format ascii

extracting a public certifcate
-------------------------------
runmqakm -cert -extract -label ibmwebspheremqmyssl -db mysslkey.kdb -target mysslpub.arm


Adding genpub.arm(public certficate from application keystore) in myssl key repos
-----------------------------------
runmqakm -cert -add -label genpub -file /var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl/temp/genpub.arm -db mysslkey.kdb
```

To create generic keystore for java application:

```
cd /var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl/temp

Creating key store key database
-------------------------
runmqakm -keydb -create -db genkey.kdb -pw gen@123 -type cms -stash

creating selfsigned certificate:  
-------------------------------
runmqakm -cert -create -label ibmwebspheremqgen -db genkey.kdb -dn "CN=GEN,OU=IBM" -expire 365 -size 1024 -format ascii

extracting a public certificate
--------------------------------
runmqakm -cert -extract -label ibmwebspheremqgen -db genkey.kdb  -target genpub.arm


Adding public key(mysslkey.arm) of MYSSL queuemanage in genkey.kdb :
-----------------------------------
runmqakm -cert -add -label mysslpub -file /var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl/mysslpub.arm -db genkey.kdb -pw gen@123

-----------
```

final output of certificates inside mysslkey.kdb:

```
bash-4.2$ runmqakm -cert -list -db /var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl/mysslkey.kdb
Source database password :
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!       genpub
-       ibmwebspheremqmyssl
bash-4.2$
```

final output of certificates inside genkey.kdb:

```
bash-4.2$ runmqakm -cert -list -db genkey.kdb
Source database password :
Certificates found
* default, - personal, ! trusted, # secret key
!       mysslpub
-       ibmwebspheremqgen
bash-4.2$
```

So wanted to know what should be proper way to connect to queue manager with TLS configured from java application.

Also I tried option as below:

```
 MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_CLIENT);
       MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.SSL_CIPHER_SUITE_PROPERTY, "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256");
       MQEnvironment.properties.put(MQC.MQCA_SSL_KEY_REPOSITORY, "C:\\ibm_mq\\temp\\genkey.kdb");
```

It gave me error as below:

```
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:383)
    ... 43 more
```

Even tried `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` instead of `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` but no luck

Thanks @JoshMc for input, I converted .kdb to .jks format, but I am getting error as below, for reference I pasted complete console output below:

New code:

```
 //commented useIBMCipherMappings to use default value of true
//System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");
       
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\ibm_mq\\jks\\target.jks");
      
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
```

Console output of error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructMQCD(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1418)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.constructCNO(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:1511)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQManagedConnectionJ11.<init>(MQManagedConnectionJ11.java:237)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11._createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:450)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.createManagedConnection(MQClientManagedConnectionFactoryJ11.java:487)
    at com.ibm.mq.StoredManagedConnection.<init>(StoredManagedConnection.java:97)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQSimpleConnectionManager.allocateConnection(MQSimpleConnectionManager.java:194)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.obtainBaseMQQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:874)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.procure(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:822)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.constructQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:764)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManagerFactory.createQueueManager(MQQueueManagerFactory.java:200)
    at com.ibm.mq.MQQueueManager.<init>(MQQueueManager.java:871)
    at IBMMQClient.main(IBMMQClient.java:64)
```

Why I am getting return code 2400 mentioning unsupported cipher suite:

```
 $ mqrc 2400

      2400  0x00000960  MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE
```

I tried with cipher suite: `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256` both .

If I keep

```
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false")
```

Then it gives different error:

```
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|10|main|2023-03-06 12:32:03.317 IST|SSLCipher.java:466|jdk.tls.keyLimits:  entry = AES/GCM/NoPadding KeyUpdate 2^37. AES/GCM/NOPADDING:KEYUPDATE = 137438953472
javax.net.ssl|ERROR|10|main|2023-03-06 12:32:04.154 IST|TransportContext.java:363|Fatal (CERTIFICATE_UNKNOWN): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target (
"throwable" : {
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:388)
```

Note: In my opinion useIBMCipherMappings should be default i.e. true hence I kept it commented(removed from code):

```
import com.ibm.mq.*;
import com.ibm.mq.constants.*;
import com.ibm.mq.headers.*;
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.*;

public class IBMMQClient {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       System.setProperty("javax.net.debug", "ssl");

       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\ibm_mq\\jks\\target.jks");
      
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStoreType", "JKS");
                    
       System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "gen@123");
       
       MQEnvironment.hostname = "********";//removed hostname for privacy
       MQEnvironment.port = 1419; // set the port number of the queue manager

      MQEnvironment.channel = "MYSSL.SVRCONN"; // set the channel name


      MQEnvironment.userID = "myuser";
      
      MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256";
      
      MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("MYSSL");
      System.out.println("Connected to " + qMgr.getName());
      qMgr.disconnect();
   }
}
```

Also I made sure my channel is properly configured with expected cipher suite :`SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)`
By command :

```
ALTER CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)

REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)
```

```
bash-4.2$ runmqsc MYSSL
5724-H72 (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1994, 2020.
Starting MQSC for queue manager MYSSL.


dis CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN)
     1 : dis CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN)
AMQ8414I: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(MYSSL.SVRCONN)                  CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2023-03-03)                     ALTTIME(10.57.24)
   CERTLABL( )                             COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)                           DESCR( )
   DISCINT(0)                              HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
   MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER( )                              MONCHL(QMGR)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)
   SSLPEER( )                              TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

Also I made sure the cipher is supported by my JVM , by following below link:
`https://confluence.atlassian.com/stashkb/list-ciphers-used-by-jvm-679609085.html`
And TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 is supported by my java version .

TLS settings details:

```
bash-4.2$ cd /var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl/
bash-4.2$ ls -al
total 36
drwxrws---  2 mqm mqm  4096 Mar  3 06:35 .
drwxrwsr-x 25 mqm mqm  4096 Mar  3 05:09 ..
-rw-------  1 mqm mqm    88 Mar  3 06:27 mysslkey.crl
-rw-------  1 mqm mqm 10088 Mar  3 06:28 mysslkey.kdb
-rw-------  1 mqm mqm    88 Mar  3 06:27 mysslkey.rdb
-rw-------  1 mqm mqm   193 Mar  3 06:27 mysslkey.sth
-rw-------  1 mqm mqm   749 Mar  3 06:27 mysslpub.arm


runmqsc MYSSL
ALTER QMGR SSLKEYR('/var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl/mysslkey')

ALTER CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)
```

```
runmqsc MYSSL

DIS QMGR
     3 : DIS QMGR
AMQ8408I: Display Queue Manager details.
   QMNAME(MYSSL)                           ACCTCONO(DISABLED)
   ACCTINT(1800)                           ACCTMQI(OFF)
   ACCTQ(OFF)                              ACTIVREC(MSG)
   ACTVCONO(DISABLED)                      ACTVTRC(OFF)
   ADVCAP(ENABLED)                         ALTDATE(2023-03-03)
   ALTTIME(04.45.30)                       AMQPCAP(YES)
   AUTHOREV(DISABLED)                      CCSID(1208)
   CERTLABL(ibmwebspheremqmyssl)           CERTVPOL(ANY)
   CHAD(DISABLED)                          CHADEV(DISABLED)
   CHADEXIT( )                             CHLEV(DISABLED)
   CHLAUTH(ENABLED)                        CLWLDATA( )
   CLWLEXIT( )                             CLWLLEN(100)
   CLWLMRUC(999999999)                     CLWLUSEQ(LOCAL)
   CMDEV(DISABLED)                         CMDLEVEL(920)
   COMMANDQ(SYSTEM.ADMIN.COMMAND.QUEUE)    CONFIGEV(DISABLED)
   CONNAUTH(SYSTEM.DEFAULT.AUTHINFO.IDPWOS)
   CRDATE(2023-03-03)                      CRTIME(04.24.33)
   CUSTOM( )                               DEADQ( )
   DEFCLXQ(SCTQ)                           DEFXMITQ( )
   DESCR( )                                DISTL(YES)
   IMGINTVL(60)                            IMGLOGLN(OFF)
   IMGRCOVO(YES)                           IMGRCOVQ(YES)
   IMGSCHED(MANUAL)                        INHIBTEV(DISABLED)
   IPADDRV(IPV4)                           LOCALEV(DISABLED)
   LOGGEREV(DISABLED)                      MARKINT(5000)
   MAXHANDS(256)                           MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MAXPROPL(NOLIMIT)                       MAXPRTY(9)
   MAXUMSGS(10000)                         MONACLS(QMGR)
   MONCHL(OFF)                             MONQ(OFF)
   PARENT( )                               PERFMEV(DISABLED)
   PLATFORM(UNIX)                          PSMODE(ENABLED)
   PSCLUS(ENABLED)                         PSNPMSG(DISCARD)
   PSNPRES(NORMAL)                         PSRTYCNT(5)
   PSSYNCPT(IFPER)                         QMID(MYSSL_2023-03-03_04.24.33)
   REMOTEEV(DISABLED)                      REPOS( )
   REPOSNL( )                              REVDNS(ENABLED)
   ROUTEREC(MSG)                           SCHINIT(QMGR)
   SCMDSERV(QMGR)                          SPLCAP(ENABLED)
   SSLCRLNL( )                             SSLCRYP( )
   SSLEV(DISABLED)                         SSLFIPS(NO)
   SSLKEYR(/var/mqm/qmgrs/MYSSL/ssl/mysslkey)
   SSLRKEYC(0)                             STATACLS(QMGR)
   STATCHL(OFF)                            STATINT(1800)
   STATMQI(OFF)                            STATQ(OFF)
   STRSTPEV(ENABLED)                       SUITEB(NONE)
   SYNCPT                                  TREELIFE(1800)
   TRIGINT(999999999)                      VERSION(09020000)
   XRCAP(YES)

dis CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN) ALL
     4 : dis CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN) ALL
AMQ8414I: Display Channel details.
   CHANNEL(MYSSL.SVRCONN)                  CHLTYPE(SVRCONN)
   ALTDATE(2023-03-03)                     ALTTIME(10.57.24)
   CERTLABL( )                             COMPHDR(NONE)
   COMPMSG(NONE)                           DESCR( )
   DISCINT(0)                              HBINT(300)
   KAINT(AUTO)                             MAXINST(999999999)
   MAXINSTC(999999999)                     MAXMSGL(4194304)
   MCAUSER( )                              MONCHL(QMGR)
   RCVDATA( )                              RCVEXIT( )
   SCYDATA( )                              SCYEXIT( )
   SENDDATA( )                             SENDEXIT( )
   SHARECNV(10)                            SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)
   SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)
   SSLPEER( )                              TRPTYPE(TCP)
```

Regards,
Amit M

Comment: So basically , my aim is connecting to an IBM MQ queue manager using the IBM MQ Java client libraries and SSL/TLS done using KDB file

Comment: I agree that you should open a new question - when you do, please add what kind and version of Java you are using. If you said it already, I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java clients can not use a kdb (CMS) key store.  You can use either a jks (Java Key store) or pkcs12 (pfx or p12) key store.

This answer provides a method to create a jks from a kdb:

[KDB to JKS keystore conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55233923/kdb-to-jks-keystore-conversion#55311445)

Comment: Thanks a lot @JoshMc for detailed steps for conversion from .kdb to .jks.
Now somehow my application is giving error of :2400 `MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE`.
I have edited my origional question with the suggestion you have suggested and console error output.
Your thoughts on this will be very helpful to me.

Comment: First,  SO is one question per post,  If I answered the original question,  it should be accepted and a new question opened for the additional question.  If you are not using a IBM Java then `System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");` is required.   The error 2400 is valid without that setting since the cipher is not a IBM java cipher.   When you have the correct setting it is saying it can't build the cert path  for either your client cert or the queue manager cert, I can't tell from the info you provided.

Comment: Setting `javax.net.debug` should provide more info.  You could also change the SVRCONN to have `SSLCAUTH(OPTIONAL)` as a troubleshooting step, this would tell MQ the client cert is not required,  if the channel goes running with this change then the client is able to validate the queue manger cert but not is own.

Comment: Thanks JoshMc for your inputs I will try the steps you have provided.
And yes I will mark this query as complete as its new context regarding cipher not supported, once created I will mention link here along with your new suggestion

Comment: Hi JoshMc , Thanks for you inputs in this.
My issue got resolved, by adding below additional changes in my client code: I was not providing  truststore related details in my java client code:
```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\ibm_mq\\jks\\target.jks");
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "gen@123");
```
Also along with this, in my eclipse I used java se 1.8  as IBM_MQ supports only mentioned JRE/JDK on their website.

Comment: Supported java versions for java client to connect to IBM-MQ:
https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/softwareReqsForProduct?deliverableId=0A8B49C00A0B11EABCF401BE73544226&osPlatforms=AIX%7CIBM%20i%7CLinux%7CWindows%7Cz/OS&duComponentIds=A004%7CC012&optionalCapIds=25