# Java client connection to IBM-MQ in TLS, is it possible to use any generic cipher at java client side

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq, tls1.2

In continuation to my earlier post:
[how to connect to queue manager with TLS enabled in ibm-mq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75629409/how-to-connect-to-queue-manager-with-tls-enabled-in-ibm-mq)

My IBM-MQ is configured to use SSL for cipher:`TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`
`ALTER CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256)`

Wanted to know in my java code which is connecting to IBM-MQ configured in TLS, in below line:
 `MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";`
Is there any way where I can mention in my java client I will mention some generic cipher where I can connect to IBM-MQ by whatever cipher is mentioned in configuring IBM-MQ server channel.

I tried vice versa, like in IBM-MQ client I gave cipher name as "ANY" as its officially supported by ibm-mq in their supported cipher list:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=jms-tls-cipherspecs-ciphersuites-in-mq-classes#q113220___d366e918

```
ALTER CHL(MYSSL.SVRCONN) CHLTYPE(SVRCONN) SSLCIPH(TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
```

So like in IBM-MQ side I can give ANY, I can connect to it by any cipher suite provided in my java client.

Is there any way where I can provide  generic cipher like "ANY" at java client side? So that whatever cipher is configured at IBM-MQ side I can connect to it.

Thanks,
Amit M

Comment: Hi @JoshMc,
Thanks for your inputs but ANY on the java client is giving error as invalid cipher.
MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "ANY"; as its not valid cipher for Java.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, Thanks for inputs,  I tried with TLS12ORHIGHER, ANY and TLS12 at my java client side e.g. ```MQEnvironment.sslCipherSuite = "TLS12ORHIGHER"; ```
But I am getting runtime error/exception as: 
```Exception in thread "main" com.ibm.mq.MQException: MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2400'.```

where RC:2400 is :

```bash-4.2$ mqrc 2400

      2400  0x00000960  MQRC_UNSUPPORTED_CIPHER_SUITE
```

Comment: Thanks @JoshMc, I was trying without *.
Actually I referred this link for configuring cipher at IBM-MQ side and at IBM-MQ channel side *ANY, was not working and it worked with ANY.
So same approach I was trying for JavaClient.
But I was wrong, the link which I shared was for java/JMS clients.
Thanks for clarity it helped a lot and with *ANY, *TLS12ORHIGHER my java client application is able to connect successfully.

Comment: Hi @JoshMc, It was random click which again made from accepted to unaccepted.
Infact your answer was so clear and proper so I deleted my earlier answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set any of the `*ANY` values on the client side you must have an `ANY` value on the queue manager side. You can have an `ANY` value on the queue manager a specific cipher on the client, but it won't work the other way.

I suggest you use `ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER` on the SVRCONN and `*TLS12ORHIGHER` on the java client.  (Note the `*` is part of the the java cipher value)